# VBA Adicionar "-" a cada dois caracteres para formar MAC Address

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba, macro

Gostaria de formar um endereço MAC a partir dos dados coletados de um leitor de código de barras.
Preciso que a cada dois caracteres seja adicionado um "-".

Texto de entrada:
A9B8C7D6E5F4

Texto de saída:
A9-B8-C7-D6-E5-F4

Até agora cheguei até o seguinte ponto de tentativa de resolução:

```
Function MACADddress(macaddress As String) As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Dim C As Integer
    Set C = 0

    Dim k As Integer
    Set k = macaddress.lenght

    Dim NewMac As String
    Set NewMac = ""

    For i = 0 To k
        C = C + 1

        If C = 2 Then
            NewMac = NewMac & macaddress(i) & "-"
            C = 0
        Else
           NewMac = NewMac & macaddress(i)
        End If

        MsgBox (NewMac)
    Next i

    MACADddress = NewMac
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Código

```
Function MACADddress(macaddress As String) As String
    Dim i As Long, C As Long, k As Long
    Dim NewMac As String
    NewMac = ""
    C = 0
    k = Len(macaddress)

    For i = 1 To k
        C = C + 1
        If C = 2 And i <> k Then
            NewMac = NewMac & Mid(macaddress, i, 1) & "-"
            C = 0
        Else
            NewMac = NewMac & Mid(macaddress, i, 1)
        End If
        'MsgBox (NewMac)
    Next i
    MACADddress = Trim(NewMac)
End Function
```

#### Observações

A função que você tentou fazer é para vetores e matrizes e não string.

Para strings utilize a função `Len()` para obter o tamanho da string e um loop para iterar sobre cada letra desta string.

Depois a sua lógica estava correta, somente foi adicionado a condição `And i <> k`, pois estava adicionando `"-"` após o último caractere.

Comment: Daniel, muito obrigado. Funcionou certinho aqui!